# Python and Berkeley DB versions in RedHat Enterprise Linux 3, 4, 5 and upcoming 6

Tags: python, redhat-enterprise-linux

I need to know what versions of Python and Berkeley DB are installed with RHEL 3, 4 and 5. If possible (it is in BETA now), RHEL 6 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.2.3 and 4.1.25, 2.3.4 and 4.2.52, 2.4.3 and 4.3.29, and 2.6.2 and 4.7.25.